# How to upgrade Nginx and install php-fpm on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, php, nginx

I want to upgrade Nginx via Yum, and also install PHP-FPM as usual. Most blog and online resources use the EPEL and REMI repos, but they're not working on my server.

My OS info:

```
Linux SUBDOMAIN.EXAMPLE.com 2.6.18-238.9.1.el5 #1 SMP 
Tue Apr 12 18:10:13 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Linux version 2.6.18-238.9.1.el5 (mockbuild@builder10.centos.org) 
(gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)) #1 SMP 
Tue Apr 12 18:10:13 EDT 2011
```

My Repolist:

```
> yum repolist

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * remi: mirrors.mediatemple.net
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Base
Finished
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Updates
Finished
repo id                          repo name                                                                             status
addons                           CentOS-5 - Addons                                                                               0
base                             CentOS-5 - Base                                                                         3,490+172
centosplus                       CentOS-5 - Plus                                                                                66
contrib                          CentOS-5 - Contrib                                                                              0
epel                             Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - x86_64                                        6,587+1,147
extras                           CentOS-5 - Extras                                                                          233+32
nginx                            nginx repo                                                                                     59
pgdg90                           PostgreSQL 9.0 5 - x86_64                                                                   201+4
remi                             Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Linux 5 - x86_64                                        191+1,451
s3tools                          Tools for managing Amazon S3 - Simple Storage Service (RHEL_5)                                  2
updates                          CentOS-5 - Updates                                                                        449+128
repolist: 11,278
```

The NGINX installed on my machine may not have been via Yum, I think I built it from source. Nginx is running as the main server, proxying to Apache, but now I wish to move to a completely PHP-FPM system inside Nginx.

What am I missing?

```
> yum update nginx 

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * remi: mirrors.mediatemple.net
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Base
Finished
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Updates
Finished
Setting up Update Process
Package(s) nginx available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for Update
```

Comment: Is the NGiNX repository (see file /etc/yum.repos.d/nging.repo or just `grep -i nginx /etc/yum.repos.d/*`) enabled? If it is not, you need to enable it when using yum with `--enablerepo`.

Comment: Yes to both. 

`   > cat /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo 
    [nginx]
    name=nginx repo
    baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/centos/$releasever/$basearch/
    gpgcheck=0
    enabled=1
`

And this too: 

`   > grep -i nginx /etc/yum.repos.d/*
    /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo:[nginx]
    /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo:name=nginx repo
    /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo:baseurl=
    http://nginx.org/packages/centos/$releasever/$basearch/
`

Comment: Oops. Sorry. Code formatting doesn't work. Here's the results of the two commands: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2b91b85957bb0c7364e2